# Мобильная игра на Android вылетает при переключении панелей Unity 2D

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-ui

Всех приветствую, у меня есть проблема и я очень хочу с ней разобраться. Я создал 2D мобильную игру на Unity и у меня появилась проблема с оптимизацией. Я прикрепил видео, это сцена магазина с компьютера. На ней все работает, но когда запускаешь игру с телефона в первый раз, мало того что при переходе на сцену магазина она очень долго грузится, чего я тоже не понимаю, может у кого то есть ответ, так еще и при нажатии на панель с названием "Donate", игра так же довольно сильно подвисает но панель все таки переключается, а если потом нажать еще и на панель с ежедневными наградами (как я показываю на видео) то игра просто вылетает. Так же в обратную сторону если при первом открытие игры ты можешь нажать на ежедневные награды и все будет работать хорошо, то потом уже нажимая на панель "Donate", игра вылетает. Самое интересное - что при повторном заходе игра хоть и с неприятными провисаниями, но работает как надо. Есть предположения что это из за слишком большого кол-во элементов и текста. Всего у меня кстати на сцене 18 / 31 drawcalls ( скрины прикрепил ), я их уменьшил при помощи создания Sprite Atlas. Может у кого то были похожие проблемы? Я бы хотел и исправить вылеты / краши, и подвисания.

Видео со сценой:
[https://youtu.be/T6tOG_StW68[![Код](https://youtu.be/T6tOG_StW68%5B!%5B%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B4) на кнопках при открытии панели][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lz7EC.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lz7EC.png)
[image: Unity Stats][image: Unity Stats]

---

Только что обнаружил эту же ошибку на другом девайсе, я ни о чем не подозревал, но абсолютно такие же баги и вылеты, кажись, исправились только у меня на телефоне. Не знаю насчет других телефонов, но когда я случайно проверил игру с другого девайса, увидел что происходит тоже самое. Не знаю что делать. Создал тему со скриншотами : https://forum.unity.com/threads/very-strange-bug-error-that-causes-an-application-crash.1239592/

Answer (score 1):

Я разобрался. Проблема была как я и думал не в количестве элементов или скрипте. Просто ошибка в движке. Обновил с 2020 до 2021 Unity Editor и все работает идеально, никаких зависаний и никаких вылетов!